# UIWebView Goes Blank

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I am loading a url in a `UIWebView` as below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MainWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.odysseynewsmagazine.net")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        self.MainWebView!.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

`IBOutlet` is connected and my `.plist` has `App Transport Security Settings` and `Allow Arbitrary Loads` set to `YES`.

Why is the app building a blank page?

Comment: Yep. It was my web connection being wonky. It worked fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")! // it works ? Comment line and uncomment the following one
    // let url = URL(string: "http://www.odysseynewsmagazine.net")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    mainWebView.load(request) // var should start with lower case
}
```

If it works, change the URL. If it doesn't work only with your URL then there's something wrong with either the site or ATS. Paste the console output.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is just fine!!!**

Your issue is you have missed add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key in your  `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary and set value to TRUE

**To fix this you only need replicate the below image in your plist**

[image]

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

**Your webView rendering the webView content, your code is unchanged**

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So here is the normal web-view loading your URL with just the App transport security setting

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.odysseynewsmagazine.net")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
    self.webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}
```

And the plist setting set to

> Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES.

[image]

And result is: 
[image]